# Placing blue dot in mapKit with a desired location

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, mapkit, location

For demonstration purpose, i need to simulate the user location in a Mapkit view.
It seems that it is possible with an undocumented API to  place the blue dot anywhere on the map view.
Unfortunately, i don't know witch undocumented API to use ?
Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set this?

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

Setting a specific location is a bit more difficult, but certainly do-able without undocumented APIs. See code below:

```
- (void)animateToSelectedPlace:(CGFloat)zoomLevel {
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = [self getCoordinateFromComponents:chosenLatitude:chosenLongitude];

    MKCoordinateSpan span = {zoomLevel,zoomLevel};
    region.span = span;

    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}

-(CLLocationCoordinate2D)getCoordinateFromComponents:(NSNumber*)latitude:(NSNumber*)longitude {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
    coord.latitude = latitude.doubleValue;
    coord.longitude = longitude.doubleValue;
    return coord;
}
```

Comment: I have tested with showsUserLocation=YES. but i need to set the blue point to a SPECIFIC location.
Any idea, sample code ?

Comment: Thank you for your help.
It'is not working.
If i understand well, the animateToSelectPlace function is used to set the map location (center on the region definition) with animation.

I have set mapView.showsUserLocation=YES but not blue point is displayed on the center of the map...

Any other idea ?

Comment: You can probably turn showsUserLocation off, as that won't help you zoom to a specific point. What are you passing in as the zoomLevel? Try something like 0.02 to start with. And are you sending in valid lat/long values?

Comment: Hi,
I have set a correct long/lat before the map is correctly centered on this point with the correct zoom Level.
The pb i have is that not blue point is displayed on the center...
I really think that it is not possible without using undocumented API... The blue point is provided by the location returned by the LocationManager...
Any other idea

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that it is possible to set CUSTOM user location (usually people use image simulating blue user point). Though i am not 100% sure, so you have a chance to try something like this to check if it is possible to deal with userLocation as with MKAnnotation ...

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D c = self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate;
[[self.mapView userLocation] setCoordinate:c];
```